# Polars how to bin a datetime type column

Tags: python, datetime, python-polars

I am trying to bin a date column. I was able to do that fairly easy using Pandas library. But I am getting the following error with Polars:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\workspace\polars.py", line 4, in <module>
    pl.col("ts").cut(
  File "\venvs\polars\Lib\site-packages\polars\utils\deprecation.py", line 192, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "\venvs\polars\Lib\site-packages\polars\expr\expr.py", line 3716, in cut
    self._pyexpr.cut(breaks, labels, left_closed, include_breaks)
TypeError: argument 'breaks': must be real number, not datetime.datetime
```

My Code is:

```python
>>> df
┌────────────┐
│ ts         │
│ ---        │
│ date       │
╞════════════╡
│ 2021-10-01 │
│ 2021-11-01 │
│ 2022-03-01 │
└────────────┘
>>> start_year = df.select("ts").min().item()
>>> end_year = df.select("ts").max().item()
>>> df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col("ts").cut(
            pl.datetime_range(start_year, end_year, interval="3mo", eager=True),
        ).alias("period_bins")
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug - do you want to report it to https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues ?

For now, as a workaround, you could cast to int:

```py
breaks = pl.date_range(start_year, end_year, interval="3mo", eager=True)

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("ts").cast(pl.Int64).cut(
        breaks.cast(pl.Int64),
    ).alias("period_bins")
)
```

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, it's just not supported to bin by temporal columns, certainly a good feature request though.

Comment: Thank you! I have accepted this answer because I extended this answer to get my [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77509071/4177781).

Answer (score 2):

If the breaks are equidistant, an alternative approach would be to use [`pl.Expr.dt.round`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.dt.round.html) as follows.

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("ts").dt.round(every="3mo").alias("rounded_ts")
)
```

**Output.**

```
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ ts         ┆ rounded_ts │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ date       ┆ date       │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2021-10-01 ┆ 2021-10-01 │
│ 2021-11-01 ┆ 2021-10-01 │
│ 2022-03-01 ┆ 2022-04-01 │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution. However, I cannot use it because the months of my bucket boundaries should be independent of `ts` values.

Comment: @arman Thanks - also for providing the full solution you ended up using. I'll be useful for future readers. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

I have extended the answer from [ignoring_gravity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77495745/4177781) to get the desired results.

```python
>>> df = df.with_columns(
        pl.col("ts").dt.epoch(time_unit="us")
        .cut(breaks.dt.epoch(time_unit="us"))
        .str.replace_all("\(|]|\s+", "")
        .str.split(',')
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Int64))
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Datetime))
        .cast(pl.List(pl.Date))
        .alias("bins")
    )

┌────────────┬──────────────────────────┐
│ ts         ┆ bins                     │
│ ---        ┆ ---                      │
│ date       ┆ list[date]               │
╞════════════╪══════════════════════════╡
│ 2021-10-01 ┆ [2021-07-01, 2021-10-01] │
│ 2021-11-01 ┆ [2021-10-01, 2022-01-01] │
│ 2022-03-01 ┆ [2022-01-01, 2022-04-01] │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you also want to put values into the bins (e.g. average or sum), polars offers [`group_by_dynamic`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic.html#polars.DataFrame.group_by_dynamic). EX:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
     "datetime": pl.datetime_range(datetime(2022, 1, 1), datetime(2022, 12, 31), "1d", eager=True),
     "values": pl.Series([1 for _ in range(365)]),
     }
)

period = "3mo"
df_out = df.group_by_dynamic("datetime", every=period).agg(pl.col("values").sum())

# summing up the 1's in 'values' over 3mo effectively gives us the days in a quarter;
# Q1: 90d, Q2: 91d, Q3: 92d, Q4: 92d
print(df_out.head())
```

```
┌─────────────────────┬────────┐
│ datetime            ┆ values │
│ ---                 ┆ ---    │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════════════╪════════╡
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 90     │
│ 2022-04-01 00:00:00 ┆ 91     │
│ 2022-07-01 00:00:00 ┆ 92     │
│ 2022-10-01 00:00:00 ┆ 92     │
└─────────────────────┴────────┘
```